# retrieving the filter case of a if statement in Perl

Tags: perl, variables, if-statement

Is there a way in Perl to know directly which test in a if statement matched?

For example, the following code would print $a:

```
my $a = 0;
my $b = 1;
if ($a == 0 or $b == 0)
{
    print $XXX ."\n";
}
```

Is there such a $XXX variable?
Or the only way to do this is to filter each one at a time:

```
my $a = 0;
my $b = 1;
if ($a == 0)
{
    print $a ."\n";
}
elsif ($b == 0)
{
    print $b ."\n";
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it helps to take a step back and explain why you want to do this.

Comment: Won't this print `0` regardless of which variable was matched?

Comment: @Zaid It would be to reduce code size, i guess.

Comment: @Barmar In this case, yes, but I want to do some more complex code with $a or $b.

Comment: note that `eq` is the string-equals operator; you may have meant `==`, the numeric-equals operator.

Comment: @ysth didn't know there was a real difference, thanks

Comment: @YoannCouble If you want to check arguments, wouldn't it be smarter to do that separately instead of trying to combine code like this? E.g. `$check{'$a'} = ( $a == 0 );`

Comment: @TLP I don't really get where you are going with the `$check`. Is this variable related to the `Params::Check` module? How would you use `$check` after?

Comment: @YoannCouble If it had been related to a module, it would have been pretty silly of me not to tell you, wouldn't it? No, its simply a hash where you store the checks for each variable. What you have here is an [*XY-problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so you need to take a step back and rethink your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but you could do:

```
my $which;
if (($a eq 0 && $which = '$a') or ($b eq 0 && $which = '$b')) {
  print $which, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok, That's what I was searching for. "nothing built-in". thanks

Comment: or `if ( $which = $a eq 0 ? '$a' : $b eq 0 ? '$b' : 0 )`

Comment: @ysth Yeah, but that gets more unreadable if there are 3 or more cases, since you have to nest ternaries. Mine is nicely regular.